# An Ajax-based product search capability using the Facebook application api... Possible?

Tags: facebook

We want to integrate a product search capability from within our Facebook page.  We sell automotive parts that are vehicle specific and want to be able to populate html select boxes on our facebook page using Ajax (year, model, and make).  When the user selects their vehicle, we then want to either send them to our website, or populate a product list within the facebook page.  Is this possible?  Or does Facebook frown on tying in to external sources of data to populate HTML elements?  For an example, see the Shop By Vehicle box on jcwhitney.com.

We're facebook newbies so if you can shoot down the idea or point us in the right direction for information on how to do it, we'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use iframe tabs inside your Facebook page. When you are working in these tabs, you can use AJAX calls if they are targeting the same server that is configured into the tab application.

Take a look to this tutorial to create iframe tabs: http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/adding-iframe-application-to-facebook-fan-page/